# How to update the song's volume for a flash player using jQuery slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, flash

I'm having some trouble with the code below. the flash player has a default volume slider, but I want to use the jQuery slider to change the volume. the volume value(nr) is changing while I move the slider, but the volume of the song doesn't.

thx for your input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

DefVol=$('#ArVol').val();

PlayPt1='<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://flash-mp3- player.net/medias/player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="25" height="25"><param name="movie" value="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_maxi.swf" /><param name="FlashVars" value="mp3='


PlayPt2='&amp;showslider=0&amp;width=25&amp;autoplay=1&amp;volume='+DefVol+'" />  </object>'



$("#RegVol").slider({orientation:'horizontal', range:'min', value:DefVol,min:0, max:200,  slide:function(event,ui){DefVol=parseInt(ui.value/200), $( "#ArVol" ).val(ui.value );}

})
$( "#ArVol" ).val($( "#RegVol" ).slider( "value" ) );

$('#PlayMp3').click(function(){ 
IaSrc='song.mp3'

$('#showPlay').html(PlayPt1+IaSrc+PlayPt2)
})
})
</script>
<table><tr>
<th><div id='RegVol' style='width:150px;margin:0px 10px'></div></th>
<th><input id='ArVol' size='1' value='55'></th>
<th><div id='showPlay'></th>
</tr></table>

<input type='button' value='Play' id='PlayMp3'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the flash source or does the source exposes an external interface ?
if not , dont bother trying you cant.

EDIT : just check the documentation of the player you are using ,took me 5 seconds :

http://flash-mp3-player.net/players/js/documentation/

Comment: i did checked the documentation of the player. it's offered this option:  document.getElementById("myFlash").SetVariable("player:jsVolume", "50");
but i couldn't find a way to implement it.